# Where to download chess master games(pgn format)/databases for android for free?

Tags: learning

Self explanatory title, Most of the sites i have visited, Only allow downloading one game at once, So if i want to download several, It takes ages. So, is there is a website which allows downloading several pgn master games at once?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://www.pgnmentor.com/files.html

Allows you to download by player, by opening or by event where the game was played.

Comment: +1. I've been using that site for a while, and it's rare that it doesn't have a player/event/opening that I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2):

".pgn" file chess game databases can be opened, viewed and edited in apps that run on Android, Windows, Linux etc. There are many download sites, depending on what your looking for. For current event games try

[The Week in chess](https://theweekinchess.com/)

For comprehensive collections by players (mostly grandmasters), events or openings try

[PGN Mentor downloads](https://www.pgnmentor.com/files.html)

For annotated PGN games (which are very hard to find) I have added 950+ to my website in 9 separate downloadable ".pgn" files at

[Annotated PGN games](https://pgnchessbook.org/pgn/)

Answer (score 1):

http://smallchess.com/Games/Magnus%20Carlsen.pgn for games on Magnus Carlsen. It doesn't need to be unzipped as in pgnmentor, it's also more recent (includes the recent world championship).

Alternatively, you can download games for free at: http://smallchess.com/Games/ . Again, no need to unzip anything.

Updated: I own the site and personally prepared those files.

Comment: Worth noting that you own the site that is hosting those files, just for transparency.

Comment: Yes. I own the files. Updated for the fact.

Answer (score 1):

If you're only getting one game at a time, you are **really** hitting the wrong sites. There are literally thousands of sites you can do collections at, ranging from the University of Pittsburgh Chess Club, to Mark Crowther's excellent This Week In Chess to New In Chess's pgn versions of the games in their yearbooks and magazines. Google is your friend, in this case, because there are far too many to list in a forum post: "PGN Chess games" yields over 6 million hits and "PGN chess games database" over 300K of them. Have fun.

Answer (score 1):

I maintain a large chess games database, you can download it (and even contribute) here:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/codekiddy-chess/

Comment: Do you have a pgn-Version of this database?

Comment: No, but you can export database into PGN. I have individual PGN's but they are way too large in size (all together) for upload.